# Integrating Notificare Push Notification service manually in android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, push-notification

I am writing this post in order to help other users get through the issues i faced while integrating **Notificare** notification service in android project in android studio. as I have to integrate **Notificare, Segment.io, Branch.io, Google places Autocomplete, In app purchase** and main problem faced to me is the clashing of multiple libraries and getting of duplicate entry errors. As **Notificare** it self has the inappbilling library code, google analytics, play services and its own notification code. I tried the traditional way of integrating the library as provided in the [**notificare** android studio integration](https://docs.notifica.re/sdk/implementation/) the compile command in gradle file way, but that didnt work as i used to get duplicate entry for the inappbilling code which was already present in the library.

So here is the procedure.

Download the sdk folder from the [notificare sdk source with sample](https://github.com/Notificare/notificare-push-lib-android)
and then rename folder from sdk to notificare and then create a gradle file in the notificare folder as it doesnt have the gradle file by following steps:

**create build.gradle file manually in notificare project. and copy the following code in it:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

above code is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) link.

then in the libs folder the **notificare-push-lib.jar** file rename to extn .zip extract the zip so we can remove contents clashing with other libraries. then in the **com** folder delete the **android** folder which has **vendor-billing** folder which will clash with your in app purchase implementation.
once the folder is deleted select the contents of folder which will be like com, META-INF and re select all 3 folders and compress them to zip.

This step is very important for mac users:

as you create zip file the mac automatically creates **__MACOSX** folder which needs to be removed which can be done using following command in terminal:

```
zip -d notificare.zip __MACOSX/\*
```

this will remove the __MACOSX folder within the zip.
Now rename the zip file to  jar file with following command:

```
mv notificare.zip notificare.jar
```

copy this file and replace it in your project notificare libs folder

then in your main project **app/build.gradle**  file add following command:

```
compile project(":notificare")
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

and also add following in main project **settings.gradle** file :

```
include ':app', ':notificare'
project(':notificare').projectDir = new File('notificare')
```

Clean project.
Sync gradle.
build the project it should run and the notificare should register your device.